# Strange shading for face of wheel?

Tags: mesh, normals

I have extruded a wheel that originally looked like this:

[image]

My modified wheel now looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the shading looks incorrect, with strange dips instead of a flat surface. But the normals seem ok to me:

[image]

Is there a way I can fix this? Is there some sort of issue with my vertices causing problems with interpolation?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you maybe intend to use flat [shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html#shading) instead of smooth?

Comment: Avoid using n-gons (faces with more than 4 vertices). They cause all kinds of problems when subdivided or with smooth shading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove these vertices. They are creating n-gons. You should strive towards quad based topology (4 sides).

[image]